# Robotframework for loop continue with next test

Tags: robotframework

I have below code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     Process
Library     String
Test Template    My Run Test
*** Variables ***
@{MyList}=   item  items

*** Test Cases *** 
#name                        type                   profile          file                 test
[XXXXX_1]                   General                test.out         Profile             mode.out 
          [Tags]    TEST-XXXXX   


*** Keywords *** 
My Run Test
    [Documentation]    Run the suite
    [Arguments]       ${type}     ${profile}     ${file}    ${test}
    : FOR  ${data}  IN   @{MyList}
    \         When data is ready
    \         And tool is ran
    \         And get was success 
    \         And test suite config is updated 
    \         And testing tool is again run 
    \         Then publish test status    

data is ready
     Log to Console     "Data is ready"
tool is ran
     Log to Console     "tool is ran"
     Run Keyword And Return    Stop Test          "This is fun"
get was success 
     Log to Console     "get was success"
test suite config is updated 
     Log to Console     "test suite config is updated"
testing tool is again run 
     Log to Console     "testing tool is again run"
publish test status 
     Log to Console     "publish test status"

Stop Test     
    [Arguments]       ${msg}     
    Log To Console    ${msg}
    Fail              ${msg}
```

As per it I am running a set of keywords for all items in a list using for loop. Now I have a situation that for an item in list a evaluation failed and I have to mark that test as failure but want the test suite to continue with next items in list.

Hence assume there are 3 items in list and test case fails for 2 second item in list then code should return back to main for loop  [not continue with other keyword for 2nd item] and start test case for 3rd item.

What I observer that using keyword Fail and others stops the whole test suite. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extract the for loop from the test template into the test case and use [Templates with for loops](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#templates-with-for-loops), you could make the iterations independent from each other.

For example with the following modifications:

```
*** Test Cases *** 
[XXXXX_1]
    FOR  ${data}  IN   @{MyList}
    #   list item  type       profile     file       test
        ${data}    General    test.out    Profile    mode.out
    END


*** Keywords *** 
My Run Test
    [Documentation]    Run the suite
    [Arguments]       ${data}    ${type}     ${profile}     ${file}    ${test}
    When data is ready
    And tool is ran
    And get was success 
    And test suite config is updated 
    And testing tool is again run 
    Then publish test status
```

This would be the output:

[image]

Comment: @Programmer You are welcome. I also suggest this for reading: https://gerg.dev/2018/09/dynamically-create-test-cases-with-robot-framework/ if you are interested in more advanced yet not so official solutions.