# Running test case In loop instead of copy the code

Tags: robotframework

I have several tests in robot. the Idea of all the tests is identical:

```
- load some parameter to module
- run
- compare expected to actual results
```

The only thing is different from test to test, is the `input` and the `expected results`.

I would like to run the test repeatedly but with different inputs- and each iteration will be considered as **different test case** - Instead of **copy the same code** for all of the test cases and change the inputs.

each iteration will have its own test case tag \ documentation \ name (lets say the iteration number)

for example:

```
FOR  ${TC}  IN  @{TCS}                            #TCS is array of inputs and expected output
   *** Test Cases ***
   # edit the tag \ documentation \ test name
   module.load  ${TC['input']}
   ${output} =  module.run
   isValid   ${output}  ${TC['expectedOutput']}
END
```

Is it possible in robot?

Thanks:)

Comment: Have you looked at data driven/template cases? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style The load, run and compare is going to be the template, and the different `input` are going to your cases.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63546535/3820025
and on this part of the documentation: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates

Comment: Doesn't it make you to copy the template as the number of inputs\outputs?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then no. Anyway, I have posted an answer check it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way is to define a Keyword with Arguments and Return Values.
You can call this Keyword in every Tescase (with specified tag/documentation etc), with specified Arguments for the Test and check the Reuturn Values.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, its quite close, but here you will have to copy the test cases. number of copies = number of test cases.
is there a solution for loop over array (for example) of test cases and call that template inside that loop?  instead of copy the template x times..

Comment: Ok i understand. The easyest way i can think of is an script (for example Python), which calls the robot script with the needed data. I never used FOR loops in robot so i cant tell how stable these are.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [test template](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates) feature of the framework, especially the [template tests with for loop](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#templates-with-for-loops).

Using it would give the following advantages:

- No code duplication. You need one keyword with the test logic, that will be invoked with all list elements.
- Each iteration will be independent from the other. So if one iteration fails, the next will be still executed.
- It is flexible. The number of iterations is dynamic, you can create an input list in a test or suite setup phase.

Example, note that I am providing my inputs from a variable file.

```py
*** Settings ***
Variables    VariableFile.py

*** Test Cases ***
Math test
    [Template]    Multiplication by 2
    FOR    ${TC}    IN    @{TCS}
        input=${TC.input}    output=${TC.output}
    END
    
*** Keywords ***
Multiplication by 2
    [arguments]    ${input}    ${output}
    ${result}=    Evaluate    ${input}*2
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${output}    ${result}    Calculated result:${result} is not equal with the expected:${output}
```

Variable file:

```py
class DataSet(object):

    def __init__(self, input, output):
        self.input = input
        self.output = output
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'i:{self.input} - o:{self.output}'
        

TCS = [DataSet(1,2), DataSet(2,4), DataSet(3,6), DataSet(3,7), DataSet(4,8)]
```

This is the output:

[image]