# Executing Robot Framework scripts under different instances/urls

Tags: robotframework

Im looking for suggestions on the best approach to handle the below.

The ask is, run my scripts for 200 instances. The only things that would change would be url and username and passwords

Does anyone know what would be the best way to accomplish this? I was hoping for some kind of loop.

Comment: Anything you have tried? Share your code/approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running test case In loop instead of copy the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915578/running-test-case-in-loop-instead-of-copy-the-code)

Comment: By "my scripts" do you mean a suite of robot tests?

Comment: Sorry, Yes suites

Comment: Do you want to run the tests in parallel? Or can they be run sequentially?

Comment: Sequentially would be best.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by utilizing template feature: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates
and passing lists with your url, username, password as a parameters

Comment: Thats exactly what I did.. Thanks